# Ember.js: Stuck with initial integration test

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, qunit, ember-testing

I'm in the process of grokking Ember after the 1.0 release, and thought was going well at it until I tried following [this tutorial on integration testing](http://ianpetzer.wordpress.com/2013/06/14/getting-started-with-integration-testing-ember-js-using-ember-testing-and-qunit-rails). It's well written and pretty didactic, but I've been stuck debugging the setup test for a few days already :/ Noob pains...

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/oliverbarnes/6466099) shows the test and the error on qunit. I'm following the setup from the tute, and which I have seen elsewhere.

On IRC somebody pointed out this tute uses R5, not the latest 1.0 release. He didn't know whether ember-testing had changed since then, but this is a possible culprit.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong? It's gotta be something stupid, I'm aware :)

(using Ember with Rails 4)

**Update**

Márcio's fiddle let me play around adding and removing stuff until I replicated the error. Turns out I didn't have any templates setup, and the test didn't like that, though the application loaded with no errors, and the ember inspector saw routes etc.

Comment: Hi I have maked a simple jsfiddle here and worked http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/GveWH/. Can you show the code executed when the transition goes to '/'. By example IndexRoute, index template ...

Comment: Marcio, thanks for this! I ended up debugging using your fiddle, and found out what was breaking - missing handlebars script tags :P

Comment: Would you like to create an answer, so I can check it as the right one? Only fair, as this has solved my problem... quickly too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working following the tutorial:

Javascript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('edit', { path: ':person_id' });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
      return this.store.find('person');
  }
});

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Person.FIXTURES = [
    {id: 1, firstName: 'Kris', lastName: 'Selden'},
    {id: 2, firstName: 'Luke', lastName: 'Melia'},
    {id: 3, firstName: 'Formerly Alex', lastName: 'Matchneer'}
];

App.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
App.setupForTesting();
App.injectTestHelpers();

function exists(selector) {
  return !!find(selector).length;
}

module("Ember.js Library", {
  setup: function() {
    Ember.run(App, App.advanceReadiness);
  },
  teardown: function() {
    App.reset();
  }
});

test("Check HTML is returned", function() {

  visit("/").then(function() {
    ok(exists("*"), "Found HTML!");
  });

});
```

Templates:

```
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
<div id="ember-testing-container"><div id="ember-testing"></div></div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>ember-latest jsfiddle</h1>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h2>Index Content:</h2>
  <ul>
  {{#each}}
      <li>{{#link-to 'edit' this}}  {{firstName}} {{lastName}} {{/link-to}}</li>
  {{/each}}
   </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="edit">
  <h2>Edit:</h2>
  <p id='name'>
      {{firstName}}
  </p>
</script>
```

Here is fiddle with this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/GveWH/